# Is it possible to see market data for options trading?

Tags: united-states, options, trading, price, quotes

Is it possible to see market data for options trading, i.e. that shows all placed option orders?

Some brokerage platforms provide "level 2" order book information of all placed stock orders in the market with prices bid/asked and quantity, but I do not see similar information for options.

For example: for a stock with strike price 'x' exp date 'dd/mm/yyyy' these are all the listed orders are being placed for this contract price. For a stock, these trading platforms provide clear information nicely in tabular form with buys and sells along with price and quantity.